# Limitations to file path and filename lengths in macOS and/or iOS / iPadOS?

Tags: macos, ios, filesystem, ipados, files.app

Are there any limitations to the lengths of file names, and file paths, in MacOS? What about iOS and iPadOS?

Answer (score 3):

iOS devices (Watches, iPads, everything) use APFS, the same as Mac.

The filename length is limited to 255 UTF-8 characters. (Therefore double-byte characters would count as 2.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits

There may also be a limit for the total characters in a filepath. (Documentation on APFS is somewhat limited.)

The colon <kbd>:</kbd> is an invalid character.

Comment: Are you saying max length is however many UTF-8 characters fit in 255 bytes? I thought it was 255 UTF-8 characters which can each be 1 to 4 bytes in length.

Comment: By experiment (with 1-byte characters in names) I can confirm your finding of 9 years ago that path length is limited in Finder to around 1000 characters. But not in Terminal and hence not in the file system. I have seen unconfirmed suggestions that there is no limit to path length in the file system.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no difference between HFS+ and APFS regarding file name and path lengths.